# Center a div or span while between other spans

Tags: html, css, center

I have a div container in which there are already 2 spans: one floating left and one floating right. Now I want to add a third span that will be in the center of the div.

I've tried a ton of things, most promising tracks include things like this on the span that is supposed to be the center one:

```
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
```

I've even tried using the  tags and coupled it with position:absolute which almost gives what I want except the centered text is on another line.

The left floating element has no styles to it as default is left floating
The right floating element has nothing except:

```
float:right;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to put `text-align: center` to the *parent* div:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
div>span:first-child {
  float: left;
}
div>span:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Left</span>
  <span>Center</span>
  <span>Right</span>
</div>
```

---

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls6zt75y/)

Comment: Is there a way to add padding to the right span without affecting the position of the center span?

Answer (score 0):

Use auto margin left and right on an element you want to be centered:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem, I have created an example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8e3au9ay/

Basically, in HTML, do something like following,

```
<div>
    <span style="float: left;">span 1</span>
    <span style="float: right;">span 2</span>
    <span class="centered-span">span 3</span>
</div>
```

and in CSS,

```
div{
    position: relative;
}
span.centered-span{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20.6px; //half of width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do this

Create Three spans with the same class

ex.

```
<span class="spanNext"> Span 1 </span>
<span class="spanNext"> Span 2 </span>
<span class="spanNext"> Span 3 </span>
```

Then I would use the following css on the class "spanNext"

```
.spanNext{
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px; 
}
```

This would set a global Class for all the three spans all using the same class which will always float left until end of page is reached since I am using percentage as a width.

Now If you want to add a margin to each span as a seperator / space between one span and another I would include the following

```
margin-left: 3px; //in the same css of class '.spanNext'
```

and to exclude the last div from having a margin left too You should include this in the css

```
.spanNext:last-child{
     margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

and if your are using SCSS / SASS {The Best in my Opinion}

```
.spanNext{
    &:last-child{
       margin-left: 0px !important;
    }
}
```